# Fragment transactions add/detach and action bar tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using the action bar tabs for displaying some images under different categories.for eg: There are three tabs:-cat1,cat2,cat3.All three show images in a grid view.The Tab Listener class looks like below:-

```
@Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        switch(id){
        case 1:{
            this.tagName="cat1";

            Cat1 genf=(Cat1)= getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(this.tagName);
            if(genf==null){
               genf=Cat1.newInstance();
               ft.add(R.id.therightframe,genf,tagName);
             }else{
               ft.attach(genf);
            }

            this.fragment=genf;
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            this.tagName="cat2";
             Cat2 genf= (Cat2) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(this.tagName);
             if(genf==null){
                 genf=Cat2.newInstance();
                 ft.add(R.id.therightframe,genf,tagName);

            }else{

              ft.attach(genf);

            }
             this.fragment=genf;
             break;
        }
        case 3:{
            this.tagName="Cat3";
            Cat3 genf= (Cat3) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(this.tagName);
             if(genf==null){
             genf=Cat3.newInstance();

                    ft.add(R.id.therightframe,genf,tagName);

            }else{

                    ft.attach(genf);

            }
             this.fragment=genf;
             break;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    ft.detach(fragment);

    }
```

Now if a person clicks on any image on the gridview I do a fragmenttransaction.replace and load a new Fragment in the same space.Yes I dont start a new activity. Till this things work fine. But when I select Cat2 tab after this, it does not replace the fragment created in the last step(when the image in the grid was clicked) and that seems natural also because in the tab listener class I am nowhere emptying the ui, i am just adding and detaching. How can this be resolved. I dont want to use replace in the tab listener because if I do that I would have to recreate those fragments which will be a costly affair